# unable to install npcap: failed to create the npcap service: 0x80070005

Tags: npcap

I am having an error with installing npcap 1.6 with my window 10 laptop. As suggested, I tried to reinstall the installer (1.6) many times but none worked. Here was what I had:
[image]

How can I fix this error?
Thank you, Huy Nguyen.